# How to pass value into array in node

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sequelize.js, koa

Hi Im still learning node and trying something cool with javascript nodejs.
Meanwhile I got stuck when pass separate "where" sequelize statement into one. 
Okay, this is my current code :

```
var periodsParam = {};
        periodsParam = {
            delete: 'F',
            tipe: 1,
            variantid: (!ctx.params.id ? ctx.params.id : variants.id)
        };

        if (ctx.query.country) {
            periodsParam = {
                country: ctx.query.country
            };
        }

        console.log(periodsParam);
```

From code above, its always return `{ country: 'SG' }` , but I want to return `{ delete: 'F', tipe: 1, variantid: 1, country: 'SG' }`

How can I resolve that ?

Anyhelp will appreciate, thankyouu.

Comment: BTW: You don't add something to an array but to an *object*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you're using `=` sign with `periodsParam` 3 times and you end up with `periodsParam` returning only `country`, because of this lines:

```
if (ctx.query.country) {
  periodsParam = {
    country: ctx.query.country
  };
}
```

Instead of assigning new object to `periodsParam`, use dot notation to add another key-value pair, like this:

```
if (ctx.query && ctx.query.country) { //before accesing .country check if ctx.query is truthy
  periodsParam.country = ctx.query.country;
}
```

As [@Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3756843/paul-rey) suggested, condition should be `ctx.query && ctx.query.country` - it will prevent TypeError if `ctx.query` is `undefined`.

Comment: You also need to verify if `ctx.query` is not undefined before trying to access `ctx.query.country` or you'll have a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined` exception. It results in `if (ctx.query && ctx.query.country) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that you were always re initializing it. You should set it as a property of the existing object.

Update from

```
periodsParam = {
    country: ctx.query.country
};
```

to

```
periodsParam.country = ctx.query.country;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just assign the Object like this:

`periodsParam = Object.assign({}, periodsParam, { country: ctx.query.country });`

Comment: As described in the [MDN web docs - Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), this method copy the values of all enumerable own properties. First, you don't need to pass the first parameter `{}` since you want to assign into `periodsParam`: `Object.assign(periodsParam, { country: ctx.query.country });`. Additionally, this method creates a new object and we don't need it to. Why would you create a new object to assign it to our previous variable?